# How to use interface and observable in angular module to display results using *ngFor from the result from HTTP GET request?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use interface as data type in angular app, but I keep getting error. I understand what the error means, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"id":1,"type":"Diagnostic"},{"id":2,"type":"Impact"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
<mat-label>Select a report type</mat-label>
<mat-select placeholder ="Report Type" formControlName="reportType" required>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let report of reportTypes"  [value]=report>
    {{ report.type }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Interface**

```
export interface IReportTypes{
  id: number;
  type: string;
}
```

**Component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  reportForm: any;

  reportTypes: Array<IReportTypes>;

  reportType: string;
  teamCode: string;
  orgName: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _el: ElementRef,
    private reportTypesService: ReportTypesService,
    private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.createForm();

    this.getReportTypes();

  }


  getReportTypes() {

    this.reportTypesService.getReportTypes().subscribe(
      reportTypes => {
      this.reportTypes = reportTypes; console.log(typeof(reportTypes)), //<--- string
        error => console.log(error)});
    
  }

}
```

**Service**

```
 export class ReportTypesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) { }


 
  // get report types available. This is returned from REST API provided by R
  getReportTypes(): Observable<IReportTypes[]> {

    return this.http.get<IReportTypes[]>('/api/v1/reportTypes');
   

  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried several different variations (too many to count and mention), but none of those work in declaring array. So, I wanted to see what is the value that the service is returning. So, I printed out the following in the component after

`this.reportTypes = reportTypes; console.log(typeof(reportTypes))`. The result was `[`. So, it seems like to that the service is literally sending the results as `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.http.get<IReportTypes[]>` doesn't actually convert the data to an array of `IReportTypes`, you are just asserting that it is.

If you are getting data as a string back from the server (Angular should try to run JSON.parse on it automatically if you are on a recent version and the response says its JSON), you will ned to better format your data in a map function.

```js
// get report types available. This is returned from REST API provided by R
  getReportTypes(): Observable<IReportTypes[]> {

    return this.http.get<IReportTypes[]>('/api/v1/reportTypes').pipe(
       // import map from rxjs/operators in your service
       map(response => {
         // depending on what response is, you will need to format it, possibly JSON.parse again
         console.log(typeof response, response);
         let reportTypes = JSON.parse(response);
         return reportTypes;
       });
    );
  }
```

You can also check in the Network tab from Chrome to see the raw response from the server along with Headers.  If its not sending the data as JSON or its in extra quotes, thats likely while it's still a string.

Comment: that's a great point! I changed my R to return as json. This is the new response I'm getting `"[\"[{\\\"id\\\":1,\\\"type\\\":\\\"Diagnostic\\\"},{\\\"id\\\":2,\\\"type\\\":\\\"Impact\\\"}]\"]"`

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with R and how to send proper JSON data back.  Looks like its escaping things a little too much with all the `\\` in it.

Comment: yes, that's what it seems like. I'll fix R, but just wanted to acknowledge your input and suggestion. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: quick question: `R` is sending request like this: `[{"id":1,"type":"Diagnostic"},{"id":2,"type":"Impact"}]` when I check in the browser http://localhost:5762/reportTypes, but the raw response in Network Tab shows this: `"[{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"Diagnostic\"},{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"Impact\"}]"`, and I still have the same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, not sure.  My first google hit for R and JSON seems a little similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592738/how-to-send-json-response-using-plumber-r but I'm not sure if you are using the plumber library.

Answer (score 0):

change reportTypes: Array;

to

reportTypes: Array<IReportTypes[]>;

or

reportTypes: Array<IReportTypes[]> = [];

try this out  <mat-option *ngFor="let report of reportTypes | async"  [value]=report>

Comment: That gives me an error: `Type 'IReportTypes[]' is not assignable to type 'IReportTypes[][]'`